# How to prevent dismissing of AVPictureInPictureController after end of the video

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, avplayerlayer, picture-in-picture

I am using AVPlayerLayer and AVQueuePlayer to play videos. I assigned AVPlayerLayer to AVPictureInPictureController to support PIP. If I am playing 4 videos then after ending of the 4th video AVPictureInPictureController is disappearing.

I do not want this disappearing behaviour of the AVPictureInPictureController, after end of the videos PIP should stay on the screen.

Comment: Put on pause before end?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Pause stops the PIP and it worked but is there other way?